# Chef: Upgrade chef-client version during knife boostrap on node

Tags: chef-infra, knife

Suppose you bootstrap an Ubuntu node through your Chef Workstation via "knife bootstrap" specifying the chef-client version to install on node using the parameter "**--bootstrap-version**" as "**12.9.41**".

At the end of the bootstrap operation checking for the chef-client version on node you'll get the one specified on knife command:

```
[root@myhostname greg]# chef-client -v
Chef: 12.9.41
```

Suppose now you want to upgrade the chef-client version on your node. For example because a new cookbook on your runlist needs a newer version to work.

If you run again the bootstrap command specifying instead "**--bootstrap-version 12.10.24**" at the end the chef-client is still the same on node:

```
[root@myhostname greg]# chef-client -v
Chef: 12.9.41
```

On knife bootstrap command stdout you get also:

```
34.210.102.44 [sudo] password for greg: -----> Existing Chef installation detected
34.210.102.44 Starting the first Chef Client run...
34.210.102.44 Starting Chef Client, version 12.9.41
```

**Is there a way to tell knife to "force" version specified on "--bootstrap-version" even if another chef-client version is installed on node?**

> WORKAROUND

I found another way to do it using the "**--bootstrap-install-command**" parameter on knife bootstrap command and specifying a bash command that goes to remove and install the target version manually:

```
--bootstrap-install-command "sudo apt-get remove chef -y && curl -LO https://omnitruck.chef.io/install.sh && sudo bash ./install.sh -v 12.10.24 && rm install.sh"
```

After the execution the chef-client version on node is the new one:

```
[root@myhostname greg]# chef-client -v
Chef: 12.10.24
```

Some details about my test case scenario:

```
[ChefServer]
ChefServer version: 12.3.1
chef-client version: 12.5.1
berks version: 4.0.1 

[Workstation]
SO: Ubuntu 14.04
Workstation Knife version: 12.19.36

[Node]
SO: Ubuntu 14.04
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, as the name implies `bootstrap` is only for the initial bootstrap and not long term maintenance. There are a number of cookbooks to aid in upgrading Chef itself on nodes but you'll have to check which are compatible with such an old version.

Comment: Sure. In my case I wanted to overwrite an existing node on the Chef Server. So in general, if the bootstrap is an "overwrite" one or if for some reason another chef-client version is already present on node, the **--bootstrap-version** parameter won't take effect.
I thought that in any case a bootstrap operation will have forced that chef-client version on target node.
As suggested by you I found a cookbook that allows to upgrade chef on nodes with a specific version ( https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/chef_client_updater ). Thank you!